# Override description in Pagination in Enhanced Grid

Tags: javascript, pagination, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I am using enhanced grid in dojo 1.10 version. I am using client side pagination but it is not fully client side. As there more than thousands of records in the grid so what I am doing is I am loading the first 400 records and doing the pagination on them.

I am providing two extra previous and next
button which will load the previous and next 400 records respectively. So, for 400 records it will be client pagination. If somebody clicks on custom
next or previous button by ajax call I will load them.

Now, as we are loading only 400 records so in the pagination description it is only showing
**1-100 items (if the page size is 100).** How can `override` this description with actual number of records that I have in the server.

I have gone through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018041/not-able-to-call-a-function-on-pagination-dojo-enhancedgrid) where we can define a function and override and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269985/dojo-enhanced-grid-with-pagination-need-to-access-number-of-rows-in-the-page)where there are different attribute but both of these problem solution is
not helping me. Can anyone give me some idea how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

We can do easily by using dojo.query

Each time we want to change the description we can do by-

```
query(".dojoxGridDescription").replaceWith('<div>Showing 15-100 items</div>');
```

For same if we want to filter we can do by

```
query(".dojoxGridFBarStatus").replaceWith('<span class ="dojoxGridFBarStatus" dojoattachpoint="statusBarNode">Filter 15-100 items</span>');
```